# retain toggle states of multiple elements on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to retain the toggle state of my elements when the page is reloaded. Right now, they all close on refresh.

I've tried to set a cookie on `slideToggle`, `slideUp` & `slideDown` but I have never used cookies before in this context.

**jQuery**

```
/* global jQuery */
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    // The element to hide/reveal
    $( '.bodhi-hide-reveal' ).hide();
    $( '.bodhi-reveal-trigger' ).removeClass( 'closed' );

    // The trigger to hide/reveal
    $( '.bodhi-reveal-trigger' ).click( function( e ) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Target only the next element to hide/reveal and toggle it
        $( this ).next( '.bodhi-hide-reveal' ).slideToggle();

        // Toggle the trigger class
        $( this ).toggleClass( 'closed' );

    });

    // Expand/collapse all button
    $( '.expand-collapse-all' ).click( function( e ) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Check if there is at least one closed div
        if ( $( '.bodhi-reveal-trigger.closed' ).length ) {

            $( '.bodhi-reveal-trigger' ).removeClass( 'closed' )
            $( '.bodhi-hide-reveal' ).stop().slideUp();

        } else if ( $( '.bodhi-reveal-trigger.opened' ).length )  {

            $( '.bodhi-reveal-trigger' ).addClass( 'opened' )
            $( '.bodhi-hide-reveal' ).stop().slideDown();

        } else {

            $( '.bodhi-hide-reveal' ).slideToggle();

        }

    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="expand-collapse-all">
    Expand / Collapse All
</button>
<div class="bodhi-reveal-trigger">
    <button>The Trigger</button>
</div>
<div class="bodhi-hide-reveal">
    <p>Some content inside the div that will be hidden and revealed.</p>
</div>
<div class="bodhi-reveal-trigger">
    <button>The Trigger</button>
</div>
<div class="bodhi-hide-reveal">
    <p>Some content inside the div that will be hidden and revealed.</p>
</div>
<div class="bodhi-reveal-trigger">
    <button>The Trigger</button>
</div>
<div class="bodhi-hide-reveal">
    <p>Some content inside the div that will be hidden and revealed.</p>
</div>
<div class="bodhi-reveal-trigger">
    <button>The Trigger</button>
</div>
<div class="bodhi-hide-reveal">
    <p>Some content inside the div that will be hidden and revealed.</p>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Benbodhi/5k9syzhj/

Comment: Can you add your html and css

Comment: This is written as a standalone piece so I can attach the class bodhi-reveal-trigger to anything I want to use as a trigger and bodhi-hide-reveal on any other element. The trigger will then toggle the next bodhi-hide-reveal element, effectively allowing me to turn anything into an accordion. I have added some HTML and a fiddle to the original question.

Comment: use ``localStorage`` to set and get the items. You might need to change some html to identify each accordion. May i change the HTML so I can help you?

Comment: Of course, I appreciate any help! I was looking to use `localStorage` actually, but just can't seem to figure it out. I also just noticed my expand/collapse all stops working after doing both, for example I hit a few separate triggers, then the collapse/expand all button - they all collapse, then i hit it again and they all open... this is normal.. but from there, it doesn't work anymore :( So my code isn't working entirely.

Comment: EDIT: I updated the code to work as expected. Just need to figure out the cookies to retain their state on page reload.